# <lightning:datatable> How to set class or icon to data cell?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I'm trying to use lightning:datatable component to render table of my custom data.

I do generate myData like:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartArray();

    for (all territories to populate country column){
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('country', territory);

        for (all dynamic fileds){
            if(yes condition){
                gen.writeStringField(b.id, 'Yes');
            }else{
                gen.writeStringField(b.id, 'No');
            }
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
```

so my JSON looks like:

```
[
   {country: "A" , id001: "Yes", id002: "No" ... id007: "Yes"},
   {country: "B" , id001: "No", id002: "Yes" ... id007: "Yes"}...]
```

so number of columns (id) can be different and yes/no values checked for all of them with some background logic.

in the helper I assign it like this:

```
component.set('v.columns', result.lstDataTableColumns);
component.set("v.dataTable", JSON.parse(result.JSONDataTable));
```

My table has proper Yes/No values in proper cells but how can I customize cell classes or add icons to cells? I need to add Green/Red background or Yes/No icons to data cells based on Yes/No values in them. Is it possible to assign `cellAttributes` to `data` attribute same way as to `columns` attribute of `lightning:datatable`?

Or it is easier just go with `<aura:iteration>`? `lightning:datatable` looks cool and has a lot of additional stuff to play with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did figured this out! Found out that it is possible to provide `cellAttributes` properties like an `Object`.

```
cellAttributes: { iconName: `columnName` }
```

It is possible to assign values to `iconName` dynamically by providing column name to grab the value from.

In my case number of columns can be dynamic and names are also dynamic. So I used Object ids for fieldName and just made another columns in format `objectId_ico` where I did assign different icon names.

I did the whole table structure on backend.

```
for(MyObject__c b:myCollection){
    Map<String, Object> btn = new Map<String, Object>(); //obj to hold cell
    Map<String, String> btnLabel = new Map<String, String>(); //obj to hold cell Label
    Map<String, String> btnIco = new Map<String, String>(); //obj to hold cell Icon
        
    btnLabel.put('fieldName', String.valueOf(b.id)); //here record ID assigned to column fieldName
    btnIco.put('fieldName', String.valueOf(b.id) + '_ico'); //here recordID_ico assigned to column fieldName will be used for cellAttribute
    btn.put('label', btnLabel);
    btn.put('iconName', btnIco); // here we put object to cellAttribute
...
}
```

I have added to my JSON generator code from original question 2 new lines to add this additional columns:

```
if(yesCondition){
                gen.writeStringField(b.id, 'DEAL');
                gen.writeStringField(b.id + '_ico', 'action:approval');
            }else{
                gen.writeStringField(b.id, 'NO DEAL');
                gen.writeStringField(b.id + '_ico', 'action:close');
            }
```

Well, in the end I have column `b.id` (which is just Object ID) where I have labl and column b.id + '_ico' where I have icon name to associate with the cell.

So far work in progress, can be optimized a bit. However, my 1200-1500 cells table generated and rendered pretty fast. As well it also has sorting and some other functionality.
[image]

Comment: I used JSON and Map<... , ...> types to be more flexible. MAybe later will assign dataType for the cells dynamically, e.g. to show url/text/button in different cells of the same column based on the cell value.

Comment: Yes this is the same approach but you've used hidden columns (I assume) rather than hidden wrapper fields (my JS manipulated keys). Good stuff!

Comment: yes, something similar. Took a while to figure out how this datatable actually works. Seems that we can pass dynamic values for cellAttribute/typeAttribute via hidden columns (as I did) or manipulate with data in JS.  Haven't test it performance nut think whatever is preferable will work.

Comment: It works well performance wise. I am rendering somewhere like 8K (visible) to 50k (initially hidden) cells with an icon in each using treegrid

Answer (score 3):

The best you could do right now would be to render the cell as a button type, which would allow you to specify an iconName in the typeAttributes property for each cell. This probably isn't a desirable solution, though, so you'll probably want to use the aura:iteration idea instead, or you could write your own data table component using the code from SLDS (it's not *too* complicated).

Comment: Thanks! Actually was able to add icons to cells. Your advice to try buttons actually helped, first I did it for buttons, and for `text` `dataType` works the same. Just had to change `typeAttribute` to `cellAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but it's quite troublesome. I've managed to do this with a data display wrapper and assigning the icon by hand clientside (I'm sure you could do it serverside, but I thought it was easier to manipulate the Object keys as you'll see below).

This trick leverages the `fieldName` reference in `lightning:treeGrid` but I'm sure `lightning:datatable` behaves the same way.

Given the following column `cellAttributes` configuration:

```
cellAttributes: { 
  alignment: "left",
  iconName: {
    fieldName: "icon_0",
    iconPosition: "left"
  },
  fieldName: "dataCell_0",
  label: "MAR 2018"
}
```

And then the Apex display wrapper, which is now a JS Object clientside:

```
dataCell_0: "4"

... other fields in flattened format my column fieldNames look for...

icon_0: "utility:success"
```

As an FYI, I do this in my JS Helper:

```
let _self = this;
for (let row of dataWrapperRows) {
  _self.applyIconToData(row);
}

.......

applyIconToData : function(row) {
  Object.keys(row).forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    // I go through the keys for each row to look for that column's fieldName
    // because for me, I care about matching the dataCell_INDEX to the icon_INDEX
    // For you it might be easier to evaluate
    let iconKey = "icon_0";

    // some logic to assign which icon
    // I use each row's data inside the wrapper to figure this out
    row[iconKey] = "utility:success";
  });
},
```

Add a dash of CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-icon-utility-success svg {
  fill: rgb(52,168,83);
}
```

And presto:

[image]

Comment: thanks @tsalb tied to implement this approach but couldn't. At least  it gave me the right direction.